# nested json syntax for api posting python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to format my json for posting to an api, I can't for the life of me see where my syntax is off or find a decent reference to check if it's 100% correct.

Below is my code, which seems to fail at the recipient part (my guess from the below error code)

statusCode":400,"error":"Invalid parameter: recipient.state"

I have just printed the json.dump and the state gets converted correctly to the two letter. I even tried to code in a state which leaves me to believe its my syntax for the json formatting.

```
@app.route('/printlab', methods=['POST'])
def printlab():
 if request.method == 'POST':
     lfname = request.form['first_name']
     llname = request.form['last_name']
     fullstate = request.form['state']
     lstate = us_state_abbrev.get(fullstate)
     lcity = request.form['city']
     laddress = request.form['shipping_address']
     lzip = request.form['zip']
     llb = request.form['lbs']
     loz = request.form['ozs']
     lw = (int(llb)*16)
     headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
     labela = {
        "authToken": vipkey,
        "labelType": "domestic",
         "mailClass": "MediaMail",
         "weightOz": lw,
         "description": "Books and Comics",
         "sender": [
            {"firstName": sfname},
            {"lastName": slname},
            {"streetAddress": saddress},
            {"city": scity},
            {"state": sstate},
            {"postalCode": spostcode}
                    ],
         "recipient": [
            {"state": lstate},
            {"firstName": lfname},
            {"lastName": llname},
            {"streetAddress": laddress},
            {"city": lcity},
            {"postalCode": lzip}
                        ]
                }

     r = requests.post(lurl, data=json.dumps(labela), headers=headers)
     return r.text
     #return lstate
 else:
     return """<html><body><h1>No Post data homeslice</h1></body></html>"""
```

Below is the json it expects for the api.

```
{
"authToken": "KEY",
"labelType": "domestic",
"mailClass": "Priority",
"weightOz": "16",
"description": "Test Dev",
"sender": {
    "firstName": "Test",
    "lastName": "Dev",
    "streetAddress": "100 Holomoana St",
    "city": "Philadelphia",
    "state": "PA",
    "postalCode": "96815"
},
"recipient": {
    "state": "NY",
    "firstName": "Test",
    "lastName": "Dev,
    "streetAddress": "11070 Glacier Hwy.",
    "city": "New York",
    "postalCode": "99801"
 }
}
```

Anything would be greatly appreciated! About two days of head desk slamming so far.

Comment: What does lstate  equal?

Comment: lstate = us_state_abbrev.get(fullstate)

Comment: I think you missed the point! If you run the function what is the result? (of lstate, e.g if you echo out your request, what is sent for state?)

Comment: The result comes back with the correct state from the posted data. I also stated "I even tried to code in a state which leaves me to believe its my syntax for the json formatting."

Comment: Is this a publically available end point?

Comment: it is, but you have to have an api key https://docs.vipparcel.com/#Print Shipping Label

Comment: What state are you trying to send? jsonlint.com reports your JSON is correct, so its either the state is not recognized or an error on the api end.

Comment: I have tried a bunch, FL, AZ, NY none of which seemed to work.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is try hitting the development URL if you haven't already, failing that get in contact with vipparcel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My syntax was wrong. This is what fixed it.

```
labela = {
        "authToken": vipkey,
        "labelType": "domestic",
         "mailClass": "MediaMail",
         "weightOz": lw,
         "description": "Books and Comics",
         "sender": {
            "firstName": sfname,
            "lastName": slname,
            "streetAddress": saddress,
            "city": scity,
            "state": sstate,
            "postalCode": spostcode
                    },
         "recipient": {
            "state": lstate,
            "firstName": lfname,
            "lastName": llname,
            "streetAddress": laddress,
            "city": lcity,
            "postalCode": lzip
                      }
                }
```